# IOS Enterprise updates over-the-air

Tags: ios, afnetworking

hopefully this is an easy question, tho, I cannot find any specific answers.
we've gone thru all the steps to update our enterprise app OTA. My question is, can I use AFNetworking to make the call? or what is the best way to call the link. (currently afnetworking is giving me errors but it may be something on our side.) I am using afnetworking exclusively, so would rather not change unless I have to.
thanks in advance

> itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://ourServer/Setup/manifest.plist

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kiPADSetupLink]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:300];

NSLog(@"begin downloading app update");

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     // handle success

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     // handle error


 } ];

[operation start];
```

Comment: Do you use any MDM product?  (air watch, etc...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you need the system to open that URL, you can't access it yourself.  Use `UIApplication`'s `openURL:` method.